# Automatic way to create plot

Tags: plot

I would like to create plots together, How can I do it?

What I mean is that I have many columns and for every column, I need to create a density plot. Is it possible to create an automatic method in r?

Select [,2:5] and create every plot between the range.

```
d <- density(DatiMei[,2]) # returns the density data 
plot(d) # plots the results 

d1 <- density(DatiMei[,3]) # returns the density data 
plot(d1) # plots the results
```